# Create a python´s data base without loop

Tags: python, database, for-loop

i´ve trying to create a data base  in python to calculate the conversion in quantities and money. The problem comes  because we dont have a record of all the total operatio`s won, loss and open for year-month, whe only have the record of hour´s won = Hora en que se ganó (in spanish), hour´s loss = Hora en que se perdio, and hour´s created = Hora en que se creó, and we work on that to create a counter on those variables vs the date´s control, which is de yer-month since our first record 201707 and the actual year-month 202308 (and we want to sumarize all the results in year month, propietario (seller) , producto (product), business´s size or tamaño de negocio, (a meassure of bussines with amounts less than 5 mill, etc), cantidad elemento (elements less than 5 units, etc) as my boss asked). and the only way i could do it is by for loops for every of all variables that my boos asked me, and then accumulate the results to make the conversion´s calculation but as  i add more for loops the longer that runs the code takes. So I ask you if you can tell me some more efficient way to be able to do these calculations instead of so many loops to make it more efficient?.

here´s my code in python:

```
# Se importan los paquetes por cantidad
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Se lee el df 
df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/alexi/OneDrive/Documents/smartsheet/Retail0408.xlsx", sheet_name="deals list")  
# Se Filtra por Contrato
df = df[df["Negocio - Tipo Negocio"] == "Contrato"]

# Se seleccionan solo las  columnas necesarias
df = df[["Negocio - ID", 'Negocio - P$ Neto Final Modificado', 'Negocio - N° Elementos (o N° Secciones)', 'Negocio - Estado', "Negocio - Propietario","Negocio - Producto", 'Negocio - Hora en que se perdió', 'Negocio - Hora en que se ganó', 'Negocio - Negocio creado el']]

df['Negocio - Producto'] = df.apply(lambda row:  row['Negocio - Producto']   if row['Negocio - Producto'] == 'VENTANAS'  else 'CRISTALES' , axis=1)




#se divide entre un millon los montos para que no se vean tan altos

df["Negocio - P$ Neto Final Modificado"] = [monto / 1000000 for monto in df["Negocio - P$ Neto Final Modificado"]]


#se crea la funcion para ver el tamaño de negocio
def determinar_tamano_negocio(monto):
    if monto < 5:
        return 'Pequeño'
    elif 5 <= monto <= 10:
        return 'Mediano'
    else:
        return 'Grande'
    
    
# Se aplica la anterior funcion la función a la columna 'Negocio - P$ Neto Final Modificado' y crea la nueva columna 'tamaño de negocio'
df['Tamaño de Negocio'] = df['Negocio - P$ Neto Final Modificado'].apply(determinar_tamano_negocio)

# Se crea el df de tamaño de negocio

df_tamaño_negocio = df['Tamaño de Negocio'].unique()

#se crea la funcion para ver el tipo de elemento

def determinar_Cantidad_elementos(elemento):
    if elemento < 5:
        return 'Pequeño'
    elif 5 <= elemento <= 15:
        return 'Mediano'
    else:
        return 'Grande'
    

# se aplica la funcion para crear un  nuevo tamaño de negocio

df['Cantidad de Elementos'] = df['Negocio - N° Elementos (o N° Secciones)'].apply(determinar_Cantidad_elementos)


# Se crea el df de tamaño de negocio


df_cantidad_elementos = df['Cantidad de Elementos'].unique()


# Obtener lista de vendedores únicos
df_vendedor = df["Negocio - Propietario"].unique()

#Se crea la el df de productos con los productos unicos
df_producto = df["Negocio - Producto"].unique()

# DataFrame para almacenar el resultado final
resultado = pd.DataFrame()

# Se convierten las columnas a fechas
columnas_fecha = ['Negocio - Hora en que se perdió', 'Negocio - Hora en que se ganó', 'Negocio - Negocio creado el']
df[columnas_fecha] = df[columnas_fecha].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# se aplica la siguiente formula para transformar las nuevas columnas a año mes

df['Año Mes Creado'] = (df['Negocio - Negocio creado el'].dt.year * 100 + df['Negocio - Negocio creado el'].dt.month) * 1
df['Año Mes Ganado'] = (df['Negocio - Hora en que se ganó'].dt.year * 100 + df['Negocio - Hora en que se ganó'].dt.month) * 1
df['Año Mes Perdido'] = (df['Negocio - Hora en que se perdió'].dt.year * 100 + df['Negocio - Hora en que se perdió'].dt.month) * 1

df['Año Mes Creado Anterior'] = (df['Negocio - Negocio creado el'].dt.year * 100 + df['Negocio - Negocio creado el'].dt.month) - 1
df.loc[df['Negocio - Negocio creado el'].dt.month == 1, 'Año Mes Creado Anterior'] = (df['Negocio - Negocio creado el'].dt.year - 1) * 100 + 12

#Se cambian los año mes  ganados menores a los creados, para que tengan la fecha de los creados


df['Año Mes Ganado'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Año Mes Creado'] if row['Año Mes Ganado'] < row['Año Mes Creado'] else row['Año Mes Ganado'], axis=1)


# Obtiene el primer día del mes actual
primer_dia_mes_actual = datetime(datetime.now().year, datetime.now().month, 1)

# Obtiene el primer día del próximo mes
primer_dia_proximo_mes = primer_dia_mes_actual + timedelta(days=32)

# Genera una lista de fechas en formato YYYYMM desde julio de 2017 hasta el primer día del próximo mes (incluyendo el mes actual)
fechas = pd.date_range(start='2017-07-01', end=primer_dia_proximo_mes, freq='M').tolist()

# Crea un DataFrame con las fechas y números correlativos
df_año_mes = pd.DataFrame({'AnioMesCorrelativo': fechas, 'Correlativo': list(range(1, len(fechas) + 1))})
df_año_mes["Año Mes Control"] = (df_año_mes['AnioMesCorrelativo'].dt.year * 100 + df_año_mes['AnioMesCorrelativo'].dt.month) * 1


#se itera sobre productos primero



for e in df_cantidad_elementos:
    
    df_cantidad_elementos_actual = df[df["Cantidad de Elementos"] == e]

    for t in df_tamaño_negocio:

        df_tamaño_negocio_actual = df_cantidad_elementos_actual[df_cantidad_elementos_actual["Tamaño de Negocio"] == t]

        for p in df_producto:


            df_producto_actual = df_tamaño_negocio_actual[df_tamaño_negocio_actual["Negocio - Producto"] == p]


            for v in df_vendedor:

                # Filtrar el DataFrame df por el propietario actual (i)
                df_propietario_actual = df_producto_actual[df_producto_actual["Negocio - Propietario"] == v]

                    # Bucle para cada vendedor en df_vendedor
                resultado_iteracion = pd.DataFrame()

                # Resto del proceso para el vendedor actual
                for i in df_año_mes['Año Mes Control']:
                    df_propietario_actual['Año Mes Control 2'] = i

                    # Se crean las columnas contadoras de cantidad de ganado, perdido y creado
                    df_propietario_actual['Cantidad Ganados'] = df_propietario_actual.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['Año Mes Ganado'] <= row['Año Mes Control 2'] else 0, axis=1)
                    df_propietario_actual['Cantidad Perdidos'] = df_propietario_actual.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['Año Mes Perdido'] <= row['Año Mes Control 2'] else 0, axis=1)
                    df_propietario_actual['Cantidad Creados'] = df_propietario_actual.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['Año Mes Creado'] <= row['Año Mes Control 2'] else 0, axis=1)
                    df_propietario_actual['Cantidad Abiertos'] = df_propietario_actual['Cantidad Creados'] - df_propietario_actual['Cantidad Perdidos'] - df_propietario_actual['Cantidad Ganados']
                    df_propietario_actual['Id con $'] = df_propietario_actual.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['Negocio - P$ Neto Final Modificado'] > 0 and row['Año Mes Creado'] <= row['Año Mes Control 2'] else 0, axis=1)
                    df_propietario_actual['% Ganado'] = df_propietario_actual.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['Negocio - Estado'] == "Ganado"  else 0, axis=1)
                    df_propietario_actual['% Ganado añomes'] = df_propietario_actual.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['Negocio - Estado'] == "Ganado" and row['Año Mes Creado'] <= row['Año Mes Control 2']  else 0, axis=1)



                    # se crea el contador de montos
                    df_propietario_actual['Contador Monto Ganados'] = df_propietario_actual.apply(lambda row: 1 if pd.notnull(row['Negocio - P$ Neto Final Modificado'] and row['Cantidad Ganados'] == 1) else 0, axis=1)
                    df_propietario_actual['Contador Monto Perdidos'] = df_propietario_actual.apply(lambda row: 1 if pd.notnull(row['Negocio - P$ Neto Final Modificado'] and row['Cantidad Perdidos'] == 1)  else 0, axis=1)
                    df_propietario_actual['Contador Monto Creados'] = df_propietario_actual.apply(lambda row: 1 if pd.notnull(row['Negocio - P$ Neto Final Modificado'] and row['Cantidad Creados'] == 1)  else 0, axis=1)


                     # se Crea las columnas con los montos multiplicando los unos de las columnas anteriores por el monto correspondiente
                    df_propietario_actual['Montos Ganados'] =  df_propietario_actual['Contador Monto Ganados']  * df_propietario_actual['Negocio - P$ Neto Final Modificado']
                    df_propietario_actual['Montos Perdidos'] = df_propietario_actual['Contador Monto Perdidos']  * df_propietario_actual['Negocio - P$ Neto Final Modificado']
                    df_propietario_actual['Montos Creados'] = df_propietario_actual['Contador Monto Creados']  * df_propietario_actual['Negocio - P$ Neto Final Modificado']


                    # Se crea la columna columna por año mes control
                    df_propietario_actual['Monto Ganados'] = df_propietario_actual.apply(lambda row: row['Montos Ganados'] if row['Año Mes Ganado'] <= row['Año Mes Control 2'] else 0, axis=1)
                    df_propietario_actual['Monto Perdidos'] = df_propietario_actual.apply(lambda row: row['Montos Perdidos']  if row['Año Mes Perdido'] <= row['Año Mes Control 2'] else 0, axis=1)
                    df_propietario_actual['Monto Creados'] = df_propietario_actual.apply(lambda row: row['Montos Creados']  if row['Año Mes Creado'] <= row['Año Mes Control 2'] else 0, axis=1)
                    df_propietario_actual['Monto Abiertos'] = df_propietario_actual['Monto Creados'] - df_propietario_actual['Monto Perdidos'] - df_propietario_actual['Monto Ganados']



                    # Se ordena de forma ascendente
                    df_propietario_actual = df_propietario_actual.sort_values(by='Año Mes Control 2', ascending=True)

                    # Agrupar los datos por "Año Mes" y sumar los valores de "Cantidad Ganados" en cada grupo
                    resultado_iteracion_actual = df_propietario_actual.groupby('Año Mes Control 2').agg({'Cantidad Ganados': 'sum', 'Cantidad Perdidos': 'sum', 'Cantidad Creados': 'sum', 'Cantidad Abiertos' :'sum', 'Id con $' : 'sum' , '% Ganado' :'sum' , '% Ganado añomes': 'sum', 'Monto Ganados': 'sum', 'Monto Perdidos': 'sum', 'Monto Creados': 'sum', 'Monto Abiertos' :'sum' }).reset_index()

                    # se crean los acumulados
                    resultado_iteracion_actual['Total Ganados Acumulados'] = resultado_iteracion_actual['Cantidad Ganados'].cumsum()
                    resultado_iteracion_actual['Total Perdidos Acumulados'] = resultado_iteracion_actual['Cantidad Perdidos'].cumsum()
                    resultado_iteracion_actual['Total Creados Acumulados'] = resultado_iteracion_actual['Cantidad Creados'].cumsum()
                    resultado_iteracion_actual['Total Abiertos Acumulados'] = resultado_iteracion_actual['Cantidad Abiertos'].cumsum()
                    resultado_iteracion_actual['Total Id con $'] = resultado_iteracion_actual['Id con $'].cumsum()
                    resultado_iteracion_actual['Total % Ganado'] = resultado_iteracion_actual['% Ganado'].cumsum() 
                    resultado_iteracion_actual['Total % Ganado añomes'] = resultado_iteracion_actual['% Ganado añomes'].cumsum()                                                                   
                    resultado_iteracion_actual['Monto Total Ganados Acumulados'] = resultado_iteracion_actual['Monto Ganados'].cumsum()
                    resultado_iteracion_actual['Monto Total Perdidos Acumulados'] = resultado_iteracion_actual['Monto Perdidos'].cumsum()
                    resultado_iteracion_actual['Monto Total Creados Acumulados'] = resultado_iteracion_actual['Monto Creados'].cumsum()
                    resultado_iteracion_actual['Monto Total Abiertos Acumulados'] = resultado_iteracion_actual['Monto Abiertos'].cumsum()

                    # Se seleccionan solo las columnas necesarias
                    resultado_iteracion_actual = resultado_iteracion_actual[['Año Mes Control 2', 'Total Ganados Acumulados', 'Total Perdidos Acumulados',
                                                           'Total Creados Acumulados', 'Total Abiertos Acumulados', 'Total Id con $', 'Total % Ganado', 'Total % Ganado añomes', 'Monto Total Ganados Acumulados', 'Monto Total Perdidos Acumulados',
                                                       'Monto Total Creados Acumulados', 'Monto Total Abiertos Acumulados' ]]

                    # Anexar el resultado de la iteración al DataFrame resultado_iteracion
                    resultado_iteracion = resultado_iteracion.append(resultado_iteracion_actual, ignore_index=True)

                # Se crea el año mes anterior para ganados, perdidos y creados
                resultado_iteracion['Año Mes Control Anterior'] = resultado_iteracion['Año Mes Control 2'].shift()
                resultado_iteracion['Total  Ganados Acum Anterior'] = resultado_iteracion['Total Ganados Acumulados'].shift()
                resultado_iteracion['Total Perdidos Acum Anterior'] = resultado_iteracion['Total Perdidos Acumulados'].shift()
                resultado_iteracion['Total Creados Acum  Anterior'] = resultado_iteracion['Total Creados Acumulados'].shift()
                resultado_iteracion['Total Abiertos Acum Anterior'] = resultado_iteracion['Total Abiertos Acumulados'].shift()
                resultado_iteracion['Monto Total  Ganados Acum Anterior'] = resultado_iteracion['Monto Total Ganados Acumulados'].shift()
                resultado_iteracion['Monto Total Perdidos Acum Anterior'] = resultado_iteracion['Monto Total Perdidos Acumulados'].shift()
                resultado_iteracion['Monto Total Creados Acum  Anterior'] = resultado_iteracion['Monto Total Creados Acumulados'].shift()
                resultado_iteracion['Monto Total Abiertos Acum Anterior'] = resultado_iteracion['Monto Total Abiertos Acumulados'].shift()
                resultado_iteracion['Total Id con $ Acum anterior'] =  resultado_iteracion['Total Id con $'].shift()

                    # se crea las siguientes columnas
                resultado_iteracion['Cantidad Ganados del mes'] = resultado_iteracion['Total Ganados Acumulados'] - resultado_iteracion['Total  Ganados Acum Anterior']
                resultado_iteracion['Cantidad Perdidos del mes'] = resultado_iteracion['Total Perdidos Acumulados'] - resultado_iteracion['Total Perdidos Acum Anterior']
                resultado_iteracion['Cantidad Abiertos del mes'] = resultado_iteracion['Total Abiertos Acumulados'] - resultado_iteracion['Total Abiertos Acum Anterior']
                resultado_iteracion['Cantidad Creados del mes'] = resultado_iteracion['Total Creados Acumulados'] - resultado_iteracion['Total Creados Acum  Anterior']
                resultado_iteracion['Monto Ganados del mes'] = resultado_iteracion['Monto Total Ganados Acumulados'] - resultado_iteracion['Monto Total  Ganados Acum Anterior']
                resultado_iteracion['Monto Perdidos del mes'] = resultado_iteracion['Monto Total Perdidos Acumulados'] - resultado_iteracion['Monto Total Perdidos Acum Anterior']
                resultado_iteracion['Monto Abiertos del mes'] = resultado_iteracion['Monto Total Abiertos Acumulados'] - resultado_iteracion['Monto Total Abiertos Acum Anterior']
                resultado_iteracion['Monto Creados del mes'] = resultado_iteracion['Monto Total Creados Acumulados'] - resultado_iteracion['Monto Total Creados Acum  Anterior']
                resultado_iteracion['Total Id con $ del mes'] =   resultado_iteracion['Total Id con $'] - resultado_iteracion['Total Id con $ Acum anterior']

                    #Se crean denominadores y numeroadores 
                resultado_iteracion['Numerador Conv'] = resultado_iteracion['Cantidad Ganados del mes'] 
                resultado_iteracion['Denominador Conv'] = (resultado_iteracion['Total Creados Acum  Anterior'] - resultado_iteracion['Total Perdidos Acum Anterior'] - resultado_iteracion['Total  Ganados Acum Anterior']) + resultado_iteracion['Cantidad Ganados del mes'] + resultado_iteracion['Cantidad Perdidos del mes']
                resultado_iteracion['Numerador Conv $'] = resultado_iteracion['Monto Ganados del mes'] 
                resultado_iteracion['Denominador Conv $']   =   (resultado_iteracion['Monto Total Creados Acum  Anterior'] - resultado_iteracion['Monto Total Perdidos Acum Anterior'] -
                                                          resultado_iteracion['Monto Total  Ganados Acum Anterior']) + resultado_iteracion['Monto Ganados del mes'] + resultado_iteracion['Monto Perdidos del mes']                  
                resultado_iteracion['Conversion'] = resultado_iteracion['Numerador Conv'] / resultado_iteracion['Denominador Conv']


                # Se crea la columna "Año Mes Control Fecha" en formato fecha
                resultado_iteracion['Año Mes Control Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(resultado_iteracion['Año Mes Control 2'], format='%Y%m').dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
                resultado_iteracion['Vendedor'] = v
                resultado_iteracion['Area'] = 'Retail'
                resultado_iteracion['Producto'] = p
                resultado_iteracion['Tamaño de Negocio'] = t
                resultado_iteracion['Cantidad de Elementos'] = e 
                # Anexar el resultado de la iteración del vendedor actual al DataFrame resultado
                resultado = resultado.append(resultado_iteracion, ignore_index=True)

# Guardar el resultado final en un archivo Excel
resultado.to_excel("C:/Users/alexi/OneDrive/Documents/smartsheet/retailfinal2.xlsx", index=False)
```

ive tried to make it by bucles, but i expect to make in a way than dont take to long to execute the code

Comment: Please write everything in English.

Comment: You may find it easier to ask your question in Spanish on https://es.stackoverflow.com/